# scp remote file and append to local file

Tags: ssh, scp, cat, sftp, merge

I have multiple files to be pulled from remote server. For further processing of the files in the local server, I need to merge (concatenate) them into single file, which can't be done in the remote file though.

I am not sure how `scp` work internally, but for the best performance I believe instead of writing those files into local directory and then merge, I feel, I should merge them on the fly and then write into single file. Can you please let me know if merging (appending) the files on fly during `scp` from remote to local files possible?

If not any better idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use SSH directly instead of scp and run `cat`. Where you would do:

```
scp remote:{file1,file2...} local-dir
```

Instead do:

```
ssh remote cat file1 file2 ... > locale-file
```

Comment: Thanks Muru, How does this work internally? Does it first create files on local and then executes `cat` or directly `cat` before writing in local?

Comment: The `local-file` will be created before SSH is started, after that the output of `cat` should be dumped directly into it.

Comment: so we are doing `ssh` and `cat`. I feel this is equivalent to `ssh` and `cp`, not as secure as `scp`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Betta why do you imagine ssh and cat is not as secure as scp?

Comment: i know that both `scp` and `ssh>cat` uses secure channel supported by `ssh`, but in that case what is the significance of `scp`? `shh>cp` should have been sufficient? Pardon my ignorance!

Comment: @Betta `ssh cp` is not sufficient, because `cp` has no idea about the local system. There's no equivalent of `scp foo remote:bar` -- `ssh cp foo ???`

Answer (score 1):

This is silly, but it seems you can actually do this with just `scp`, by copying the remote files to a local fifo and piping them out of it:

```
$ mkfifo p
$ while :; do cat p >> output ; done  &
$ scp somehost:test/\* p
bar       100%    4    10.9KB/s   00:00    
doo       100%    4     8.6KB/s   00:00    
foo       100%    4    13.6KB/s   00:00  
$ kill %1
# output contains the files concatenated
```

(tested with OpenSSH 7.4p1-10+deb9u2 on Debian)

Answer (score 0):

Below steps to performed being in local server only

I tested both steps it worked fine

First step

---

```
ssh username@remoteserverip "cat file1 file2 file3 >> /remoteserverpath/Mergedfile"
```

---

Second step You are copying merged file from remote server to local server You can do this by rsync  or scp

---

I prefer rsync

```
rsync -avzh username@remoteserverip:/remoteserverpath/Mergedfile localserverpath_where_you_want_to_save
```

---

Comment: I said, I can't merge on the remote server! :)

Comment: I achieved to copy the single file content over rysnc in localserver. i am trying to do for multiple files too


below is command used to copy the single file content of remote server in local server

rsync -avzh username@remoteserverip:/path/remoteserverfile /localserverpath/Mergedfile


Merged file contains remoteserverfile content